# How do I create "internal-generic" type?

Tags: typescript

```
type DnsRecords = {
  [key: string]: {
    component: FC<A>
    toInlineValue: (data: A) => string
    fromInlineValue: (record: string) => A
  }
}
```

But for every sub-object, `A` can be different.

For example:

```
type DnsRecords = {
  a: {
    component: FC<{ a: number }>
    toInlineValue: (data: { a: number }) => string
    fromInlineValue: (record: string) => { a: number }
  }
  b: {
    component: FC<string | number>
    toInlineValue: (data: string | number) => string
    fromInlineValue: (record: string) => string | number
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly. You need an extra generic type to `DnsRecords` to contain the type for each property:

```
type DnsRecords<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: {
        component: FC<T[P]>
        toInlineValue: (data: T[P]) => string
        fromInlineValue: (record: string) => T[P]
}
}
type V = DnsRecords<{
    a: { foo: string },
    b: { bar: string }
}>
```

You can create a function that will help inferring `T` but if you use different values the compiler will infer a union of the properties:

```
function createDns<T>(dns: DnsRecords<T>) {
    return dns;
}

type A = { x: string }
type B = { x2: string }

let o = createDns({ // T is { a: A | B; }
    a: {
        component: (p: A) => { },
        toInlineValue: (data: B) => "",
        fromInlineValue: (r) => ({ x: r })
    }
})
```